# Restrict xlim on kdeplot while keeping it smooth

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The following kdeplot has a peak on the left that I would like to bring more into focus:

```
a = np.array([1] * 100 + [5])
sns.kdeplot(a)
```

[image]

My usual way to do this is a `pyplot.xlim` call, but for a distribution like this, zooming in this much reveals a jagged curve, unlike the typical smooth kde curves:

```
plt.xlim(.5, 1.1)
sns.kdeplot(a);
```

[image]

Is there any way to limit the x axis through kdeplot in a way that preserves the smoothness?

Comment: I don't know much about seaborn or kernel density estimation, but the [`seaborn.kdeplot` documentation](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) mentions a `gridsize` parameter defaulting to 100, representing "Number of discrete points in the evaluation grid". That sounds like it might be what you want. (If it *is* what you want, you probably should have been able to find that yourself by googling `seaborn kdeplot`.)

Comment: This gets rid of the jagged edges, thanks. If you want to turn it into an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`seaborn.kdeplot`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) accepts a `gridsize` parameter defaulting to 100, representing "Number of discrete points in the evaluation grid". Raising this number should provide more detail in zoomed-in views like the one you want:

```
sns.kdeplot(a, 500)
```